# Правила вживання літери г/ґ/х при запозиченні іншомовних слів на g/h (гакер, гостинг)

Tags: правопис, запозичені-слова, transliteration

Я завжди пишу *хостинг* (від анг. *hosting*), *хакер* (від англ. *hacker*) і завжди вважав ці слова коректними.

В книзі [Волтер Айзексон. Стів Джобс. Біографія засновника компанії Apple](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%94%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81_(%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0)) можна зустріти слово *гакер*:

> То була **гакерська** субкультура - з’являлися зломщики, аматори,
>   кіберпанки, пірати чи просто програмісти, а ще - інженери, які не
>   припадали пилом HP.
>
> Лише невелика групка, яку згодом назвали **гакерами**, втішалися
>   комп’ютерам і називали їх засобами для свободи.

За що переклад був підданий критиці багатьма читачами.

Також в деяких текстах можна зустріти варіант *гостинг* (не плутати з терміном в [покері](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)) і можна знайти правила в правописі, що [підтверджують](http://www.iji.com.ua/hosting.html) саме таке написання:

> Згідно з "Українським правописом" у словах іншомовного походження `g` і
>   `h` звичайно передають літерою `г`, пор.: *gallon - галон; handicap -
>   гандикап; habitus - габітус; halo - гало* тощо. Лише в деяких словах,
>   запозичених з англійської мови, через посередництво російської мови `h`
>   передане літерою `х` (*хокей, хол, хобі*). Тому англійське *hosting* слід
>   писати українською мовою з початковою літерою `г`.
>
> Отже, правильним є написання гостинг.

Чи дійсно правильно писати *гакер*/*гостинг* чи все таки варто використовувати звичні варіанти *хакер* та *хостинг*?

Comment: А Hobbit'а видавали-видавали як "Гобіта" а кіно випустили під назвою "Хобіт".

Comment: @Artemix бо кінозали менше переймаються стилем, вони намагаються задовольнити маси, а книжники завжди докопуються до деталей.

Comment: @Artemix - «Hobbit», як пише сам Толкін, – це англійське слово і його при перекладі книги іншими мовами теж треба перекладати, воно означає «мешканець нори», та перекладачі коментарів автора не читають, навіщо собі життя ускладнювати? Я ще жодного достойного перекладу книжок Толкіна не бачив, ані українською, ані російською.

Comment: Також цікаво як транслітерувати сленгове `hack`, бо в українській вже є слово `гак`, яке означає `hook`

Comment: @YellowSky Я думаю що це було утопічне побажання Професора. Прагнення слідувати йому створило переклад у стилі псевдо-слов'янського епосу.

Comment: @Artemix - «Створило» чи «створило б»? Існує такий переклад?Там же не всі особисті й географічні імена мають перекладатися, а лише гобітські (староанглійскі) та роганські (давньоанглійські).

Comment: @Chizh  у негативному значенні *hack* я би натомість перекладав — як *злам* (*to hack* – *зла́мувати*). Для позитивного значення (див. ikeahackers, наприклад) ще треба пошукати відповідника.

Comment: @NashBridges `злам` - недостатньо сленгове слово, краще запозичити

Comment: О. Авраменко в програмі [«Експрес-урок української» № 182](http://авраменко.укр/11/12/379-urok-182-haker-chi-gaker.html) стверджує, що, принаймні, «гакер» і «голдинг» можна і так, і так. Хоча звідки він бере ті випадки, коли можна «х», і коли не можна «х», я не зрозумів. Адже в правописі сказано доволі [неясно](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par87): «*G* і *h* звичайно передаються літерою *г*… В окремих словах англійського походження *h* передається літерою *х*: хобі, хокей, хол; Хемінгуей **та ін**.» — яких саме *окремих*…

Comment: @Chizh дуже просто: `гек`. Якщо що, жартую. Окремі випадки завжди можна знайти, що не підходять під правило. Це не значить, що правило неправильне.

Comment: @Sasha facepalm. А навіщо "і так, і так"? Чим більше плутанини, тим краще?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Ця відповідь переважно стосується слів, які містять `h`. Для слів, які містять `g`, дивіться інші відповіді.

---

[Also sprach](http://zbruc.eu/node/43178) Андрухович:

> Наслідувати росіян погано не тільки тому, що їх узагалі бажано ні в чому не наслідувати, але й тому, що в них насправді все непослідовно і плутано.

Так от, чомусь *Harry* передають як *Гарри*, а *Hagrid* - як *Хагрид* (либонь, варіант "Хєґрід" все ж викликав якісь підозри). *Heidegger* - це *Хайдеггер*, а *Heinrich* - таки *Генрих*, хоча бідолашний *Hemingway* - *Хемингуэй*. Дивовижно, чи не так?

Український фрикативний (глотковий) звук `[г]` добре відтворює гортанний англійський `[h]` і дуже добре - фрикативний німецький `[h]`, то чому не скористатися з цієї переваги?

"Український правопис" 2015 року [каже таке](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par87):

> `G` і `h` звичайно передаються літерою `г`:  Гельсінкі, Гіндустан,
>   Гренландія, Греція

АЄОА:

> В окремих словах англійського походження `h` передається літерою `х`:
>   *хобі, хокей, хол; Хемінгуей* та ін.

І ніхто не знає, за якими ознаками вибирають ці "окремі слова". Іноді до цього списку потрапляє й нещасний, багатостраждальний "*хобіт*".

Втираючи рясні криваві сльози, зазначу, що передачу [`h`] через [`г`] було затверджено у так званому "скрипниківському" правописі 1928 року, а над ним працювали авторитетні мовознавці та літератори (зокрема, [А. Кримський](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D0%AE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [О. Курило](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0), [М. Йогансен](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), [М. Хвильовий](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9) тощо), а вони таки щось тямили. У 1937 році совєти вирішили, що все це - буржуазний націоналізм (чому би то?) і треба наближати 
блудну українську мову до вєлікого і могучєго. От і наблизили.

Словом, feci quod potui, нехай [ця чудова стаття](http://zbruc.eu/node/43178) зробить більше.

Comment: Ви дуже влучно написали про наслідування росіян. Однак, не треба вдаватися в крайнощі, мовляв, давайте зробимо навпаки і тоді у нас все буде правильно

Comment: Не хотіла, щоб виглядало так, ніби я вдаюся до крайнощів, тим паче неможливо зробити навпаки, бо російська мова в цьому питанні сама собі суперечить, а в українській усе може бути послідовно.

Answer (score 14):

Так, дійсно правильно писати гакер і гостинг.

Сторінка [кирилізація англійської мови](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) надає такі правила:

Літера `g` транслітерується або як `ґ`, або як `дж`.
Літера `h` транслітерується через `г`.

Ви правильно помітили, що [державна служба інтелектуальної власності України](http://sips.gov.ua/ua/transliteruvannja.html) каже наступне: `х` використовується при запозиченні з російської мови. Якщо ваша мета - запозичити не російське слово з російської мови - можете використовувати `х`, якщо ж ціллю є пряме запозичення з анґлійської - тоді `г`.

Для перевірки візьміть слово `хан` і транслітеруйте його англійською, ви пишете `khan`, не `han`. То ж маємо `kh`, `h`, `g`, що відповідають `х`, `г`, `ґ`/`дж`.

Така ж сама ситуації в івриті. Там є 4 літери: 2 для позначення звука `х`, одна для позначення звука `г`, одна для позначення звука `ґ`. При транслитерації вони не користуються для `h` i `g` літерами, що позначають звук `х`, так само, як і українці, користуються літерами, що позначають звуки `г`, `ґ` і `дж`.

Причина в тому, що `h` в анґлійській - гортанний звук, як і `г` в українській. Тобто, насправді саме `г` ближче до `h`, а не `х` (в російській просто немає гортанного звука для передавання цього звуку, тому взяли найближчий до `h`).

Comment: [Шерльок Гольмс](http://i052.radikal.ru/1212/1b/c156f0f90125.jpg).

Comment: Аргумент що літера "А" у мові "Б" краще передає звучання літери "В" у мові "Г" мені не здається таким що закриває усі питання. У відриві від фонетики самої мови це прямий шлях до [варваризмів](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC).

Comment: @Artemix там на даному етапі розвитку мови саме така сітка, як і в нас: "х", "г", "ґ". Дуже чітко. І "h" знаходить поміж "х" і "ґ", але найближче до "г".

Comment: О. Авраменко в програмі [«Експрес-урок української» № 182](http://авраменко.укр/11/12/379-urok-182-haker-chi-gaker.html) стверджує, що, принаймні, «гакер» і «голдинг» можна і так, і так.

Comment: Дискуссію [перенесено у чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55137/discussion-on-answer-by-p-vovk--------)

Answer (score 3):

Я не є мовознавцем. Однак запустив google translate і обрав команду *Прослухати*:

[hack](https://translate.google.com/#en/uk/hack)

[hosting](https://translate.google.com/#en/uk/hosting)

Цю ж процедуру повторив зі словником ABBY Lingvo (в англо-російському напрямі перекладу можна прослухати звучання слів).

В жодному із перелічених випадків я не почув "Г".

Тож, можливо, не треба міряти все однією міркою. Адже, якщо в оригіналі звучить "Х", то нехай буде "Х". І теж саме з "Г".

Comment: при спілкуванні з мовцем ви почуєте [h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_glottal_fricative) порівняйте з [ɦ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_glottal_fricative) та [x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative)

Comment: Звук h придиховий, на відміну від х - у нього просто інше місце творення

Comment: Так, Ви праві. Бо звук `h` не звучить, ані як `ɦ` (звук що в українській мові відповідає букві `г`), ані як `x`. Питання швидше в тому, до котрого з цих звуків він ближчий.

Comment: Це запитання — не про звуки, а про правопис.

Answer (score 2):

> Ця відповідь переважно стосується слів, які містять `h`. Для слів, які містять `g`, дивіться інші відповіді.

---

**Правильно: гакер і хакер (подвійний правопис), голдинг і холдинг (подвійний правопис), гостинг, гостел, гінді, хобі, хокей, хол, Хемінгуей, хобіт/гобіт - не зрозуміло.**

---

Олександр Авраменко, доцент Київського університету Б. Грінченка в своєму відео [Хакер чи гакер - експрес-урок](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yk2jEGlSWrw) дає наступне пояснення:

Не правильно вживати *хостел*, *хінді*, правильно: *гостел*, *гінді*.

Лише для *хакер* та *холдинг*, які давніше освоєні українською мовою у формі *хакер* та *холдинг* дозволено **подвійний правопис**. Науковці із Інституту української мови все ж *радять надавати перевагу* написанню з `г`.

В правописі читаємо, що:

> В окремих словах англійського походження h передається літерою х:
>   хобі, хокей, хол; Хемінгуей та ін.

Які *інші* слова входять в цей список і за якою ознакою вони сюди потрапляють - не зрозуміло.

Answer (score 2):

Це радше відповѣдь на [*Чому зараз почали писати Гоґвортс, а не Хогвартс?*](/q/7166/585) і з нахилом переважно про **h**, хоча **g** теж тут згадано побіжно, бо в совєтські часи ця буква **ґ** була прибрана, тому часто в правилах з **h**. Тому і однак, гадаю, вона пасуїть і тут, бо тези збѣжні і наведені всѣ *загальні* правописи чи норми.

Тобто це радше крик тим, хто чому-сь безарґументовано висловюїть, шчо *ранѣше було гинакше*.

> <sub>Запитник</sub>
>
> Чому зараз почали писати *Гоґвортс*, а не *Хогвартс*?

Ліцензійний український переклад першої книги [*Гаррі Поттер і філософський камѣнь*](//ababahalamaha.com.ua/uk/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D1%96_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_%D1%96_%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C) — де, волосне, і ся зустрѣчаїть вперше слово *Гоґвортс* — від видавництва [*А-ба-ба-га-ла-ма-га*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90-%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%B0) побачив свѣт шче в 2002 роцѣ, шчо на де-сь 5 років пізнѣше оріґінала. Це аж-но де-сь *20 років*, шчо, як на мене, досить відчутний помѣжок часа і явно не *зараз*. Українська Вікіпедія, котру ви й навели, просто зафіксила ций факт.

> <sub>Запитник</sub>
>
> Якщо послухати оригінал абсолютно чітко чутно *Хогвартс*

Гинше слово, шчо стоїть буквально на обкладинцѣ: *Гаррі*, шчо в оріґіналѣ *Harry*, де українська *послѣдовно* передаїть вимову **h**, а московська — *нѣ*.

> <sub>Запитник</sub>
>
> Це якісь нові правила транслітераціі?

Як-шчо про передачу:

- **h** як **г**, то не нові, бо так було *завжди*;
- **g** як **ґ**, то так було не завжди, хоча би через один факт — в совєтські часи букву *ґ* було прибрано з абетки, наслѣдки котрого відчувати ймуть і наступні правописи, а саме: слабкі правила стосовно **ґ**, а також в де-котрих правилах не повернули **ґ**, наприклад про апостроф.

Це дуже нагадуїть менѣ [*Відмінювання прізвищ із закінченням **ко***](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2903/585), де питаннє теж підносить, шчо *ранѣше* такого не було, хоча так було *завжди*. Повторимо те саме, але з **h**?

Всѣ доступні наразѣ широкому загала правописи можна отримати на [Метѣ](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/119/585), де добрі або нѣ люди зібрали і упорядковали. Теж почну з новѣтнїх часів.

[2019](//ulif.org.ua/system/files/pravopus-new.pdf#page=156) § 122

> 4. Звук **[h]** передаємо переважно буквою **г**: *гандбо́л, герба́рій, гі́нді, гіпо́теза, горизо́нт, го́спіс, го́спіталь, го́мус; Га́рвард, Ге́льсінкі, Гіндуста́н; Ганніба́л, Ге́йне, Гора́цій; Люфтга́нза*. За традицією в окремих словах, запозичених з європейських та деяких східних мов, **[h]** і фонетично близькі до нього звуки передаємо буквою **х**: *брахма́н, джиха́д, моджахе́д, хано́м, харакі́рі, хіджа́б, хо́бі, хоке́й, хол, хо́лдинг, шахі́д; Алла́х, Ахме́д, Муха́ммед, Сухро́б, Хакі́м, Хаммура́пі* та ін.

Як можите побачити: *переважно* **г** — тобто це *основна* передача, а *за традіцією* і *фонетічно близькі до нього звуки* через **х**. Старѣші правописи мати ймуть де-сь подібну структуру. Однак, як гадаїте, скільки тривати йме згадана традіція?

[2015](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par87) § 87<sup>1</sup> 
[2012](http://litopys.org.ua/pdf/pravopys2012.pdf#page=61) 
[2007](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=%2FE_LIB%2FPDF%2Fukr0001261.pdf#page=119) 
[2003](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=%2FE_LIB%2FPDF%2Fukr0003960.pdf#page=99) 
[1997](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=%2FE_LIB%2FPDF%2Fukr0004079.pdf#page=99) 
[1993](//books.google.com.ua/books?redir_esc=y&id=WKzqAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=G+%D1%96+h+%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E+%D0%B3) 
[1960](//archive.org/details/up-1960/page/113/mode/2up?view=theater) § 91<sup>2</sup> 
[1945](//archive.org/details/ukrainian_pravopys_1945/page/n51/mode/1up?view=theater) § 90 
[1934](http://escriptorium.univer.kharkov.ua/handle/1237075002/10591) § 76<sup>3</sup> 
[1933](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=%2FE_LIB%2FPDF%2Fukr0004157.pdf#page=62)

> <sup>[номер абзаца]</sup>
>
> <sup>[1]</sup> **g** і **h** звичайно передаються літерою **г**: *авангард, агітація, агресор, гвардія, генетика, гімнастика, гоніометр, грандіозний, графік, грог, ембарго, лінгвістика, міграція; гандбол, гегемонія, гектар, гербарій, герцог, гінді* (мова), *гіпотеза, горизонт, госпіталь, гугенот, гумус; Гаага, Гавана, Гавр, Гарвард, Гаронна, Гвінея, Гельсінгфорс, Гельсінкі, Гіндустан, Гренландія, Греція, Йоганнесбург, Люксембург; Ганнібал, Гейне, Гете, Гізо, Гомер, Горацій, Горн, Гюго, Магомет*.
>
> <sup>[2]</sup> У деяких словах, які в іноземних мовах мають на початку **h**, відповідно до української вимови **г** не пишеться, напр.: *а́рфа, іпохо́ндрія, істері́я, істо́рія, омо́нім*.
>
> <sup>[3]</sup> В окремих словах англійського походження **h** передається літерою **х**: *хобі, хокей, хол; Хемінгуей* та ін.

Примѣтки

1. Без другого абзаца.
2. З другим абзацом.
3. Без другого і третього абзаца.

*Певна* примѣтка ся стосуїть і старѣших правописів, допоки не буде *нова певна* примѣтка. Де-котрі правописи можуть мати гинші приклади або гиншу структуру їх, але *са́ме* правило при цьому сформуловано точнѣсінько однаково або має таку саму суть. Як-шчо параґраф не вказаний, тоді він такий самий, як і в новѣшого.

[1928](//r2u.org.ua/data/other/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81-1928.pdf#page=45) § 55

> Чуже **h** передаємо нашим **г**, щождо чужого **g**, то в новіших запозиченнях його треба передавати через **ґ**, у запозиченнях же засвоєних давніше, особливо з грецької мови, віддаємо нашим **г** (порівн. § 54): *Англія, газ, газе́та, га́ма, гегемо́нія, гецеало́гія* (*ло́гіка*…), *генера́л, геній, геогра́фія* (*грама́тика, програ́ма, грамофо́н, діягра́ма, гра́фіка, грам, кілогра́м*…), *Герма́нія, гігіє́на, гімна́зія, гіпс, гра́дус, граф, Гру́зія, гру́па, дифто́нг, егої́зм, організа́ція, педаго́г, Ри́га, траге́дія, фігу́ра* й ін., але *аґе́нт, аґіта́ція, аґроном, Араґо́нія, бра́внінг, Брю́ґґе, Гамбурґ, Геґель, гіда́льґо, гуґено́ти, Гюґо́, ґарантія, Ґаро́нна, ґва́рдія, Ґвіне́я, Ґе́ргард, Ґе́те, Ґеттінґен, ґібелі́н, ґірля́нда, ґля́вберова сіль, ґлядія́тор, ґнайс, Ґо́льфштром, Ґрана́да, ґрандіо́зний, Ґріґ, ґу́ма, Ґустав, дириґе́нт, елеґа́нтний, інтеліґе́нт, лінґві́ст, міґра́ція, Чіка́ґо* і т. ін.

[1925](//elib.nlu.org.ua/files/Disk2//000000011911/jpg/0021.jpg), [1892](https://zbruc.eu/node/66463) такого правила взагалѣ не мають, хиба що треба вишуковати в прикладах гинших правил, наприклад *Гейне* і *Гайне*, що від [*Heine*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%80%D1%96%D1%85_%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5). Шчо недивно, бо в цьому потреби справдѣ немає, як-шчо знати лише українську, а не *також* московську, де **г** мала (і має в де-котрих говорах, як-шчо зберегли ся) *таку саму* вимову, шчо і українська, але в певний час внормовало ся назад як **ґ**, тому там **h** може передавати ся різними способами. Наприклад болґарська такої проблеми не маїть, тому там сістематічне і очѣковане [*Хари*](//bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8A%D1%80).

Підсумуймо? Передача **h** в **г** *завжди* була основною, а в **х** — *завжди* було *винятком* і появило ся лише в совѣтські часи шчонайдавнѣше після 1945, коли була неприхована політіка зближення мов, ось наприклад витяги з передмови правописа 1960:

> Однак від часу попереднього видання «Українського правопису» у ряді правописних моментів, спільних для української і російської мов, виникла певна неузгодженість, яку тепер, після опублікування «Правил русской орфографни и пунктуации», можна усунути.
>
> …
>
> У новому виданні «Українського правопису» усунені розбіжності в спільних моментах українського й російського правописів
>
> …
>
> У тих моментах, які за їх природою є спільні з іншими мовами (розділові знаки, правопис великих і малих літер, написання разом і окремо), забезпечити єдність з правописами братніх народів Радянського Союзу, особливо — російського, орієнтуючись на останній проект Державної комісії.

Окремо можна також згадати шчонайменше (sic!) *паспортну* транслітерацію [2010 року](//zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/55-2010-%D0%BF#Text), де передача **г** в **h** (перед де-котрими буквами як **gh**) i **ґ** в **g**.

Тобто заява про яку-сь *новизну* транслітерації чи правила сама по собі *абсурдна*.

> <sub>Запитник</sub>
>
> Якщо послухати оригінал абсолютно чітко чутно *Хогвартс*

Повернѣмо ся до цього. Тут пропушчено одне чи два слова — [*субєктівно*] *менѣ*. Це вже вѣдносно вѣдомий факт, шчо певний слухач сприймаїть невѣдомі звуки через *свою* прізму, в тому числѣ через свою основну мову, про шчо відносно нормально могли розказати *Твоя підпільна гуманітарка* ві [*Хемінгуей чи Гемінґвей*](//youtube.com/watch?v=bklEM4kGQ5I).

Так само мовник може мати вплив своєї основної мови чи говірки, через шчо маїмо явишче як акцент. Тому мови мають ортоепічні стандарди, наприклад [*Hogwarts*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogwarts) це [ˈhɒɡwɔːrts], і лише звідси розбирати вимову двох мов, про шчо тут вже було неодноразово, наприклад: [*Правила вживання літери **г**/**ґ**/**х** при запозиченні іншомовних слів на **g**/**h** (гакер, гостинг)*](/q/347/585), [*Генрі чи Хенрі?*](/q/3769/585), [*Геловін, Хеловін, Хеллоуїн*](/q/3070/585) ітд. *[Редаґуйте цю частину, як-шчо я шчо-сь пропустив]*.

Де-шчо іронічно, але шче один факт, котрий указуїть на *де-шчо* вашого *чітко чутно* — чомусь просуваїте запис са́ме *Хогвортс*, а не очѣкований за *їхньою* вимовою [*Хогуортс*](//bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%81), де **w** маїть бути записаний як **у**, шчо як в болґарів і в словѣ *Хемінг**у**ей*.

Як-шчо ж байдуже на правописні мови і дбаїте про вимову, то за [мѣжнародним фонетічним алфабітом](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82) маїмо наступне:

- Анґлійське *тверде* **g** і **ґ** мають стандардну вимову [g] і тут *жодних* суперечок. Як-шчо суперечка яка-сь і існуїть, то лише про *потребу* такої букви і звука, а це вже геть гинша тема. Зазначу, шчо навѣть коли прибрати букву, то однаково маїмо ві вимовѣ як алофон до **к**: *якби* [[яґби](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%B8)], *вокзал* [[воґзал](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB#53885)] ітд.
- Анґлійське **h** це **[h]** чи не вимовяти ся. В першому випадку це прямий *глухий* відповѣдник до **г**, шчо є **[ɦ]** і котрому українцевѣ, чого не сказати про де-котрих, вимовити геть легко, як-шчо попросити виговорити [*пошепки*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whispering) слова з **г**, бо тоді не використовуїмо, волосне, *голосові звязки*, шчо дають [*ѕвінкість*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Можу порадовати і водночас засмутити прихильників **х** — **h** в де-котрих говорах перед **[j]** можить ставати шчо-сь мѣж *зати**шш**і* і ***х**іть*, можна навѣть спробувати описати як глухий **й**, а так це **[[ç]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)**, нп. [*human*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/human#English) [ˈ(ç)ju̟ːmən], [ˈ(ç)ju̟ːmn̩]. Засмучую тим, шчо **г** перед **й** теж стаїть гиншим звуком: *бѣгти* > *бѣгйу* > *бѣжу*.<sup>1</sup>

  Примѣтка

  1. Ради справедливостї, тут від **ґ**, як в анґлійській тверде **g** проти мякого, і деафрікація. Бо якби там була відпочатку **[ɦ]**, то було би радше **[[ʝ]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)**.
- Залишило ся **х** [x], котрого стандардна анґлійська [утратила](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gh_(digraph)#English) і записуїть переважно будь-яким чином, нп. (старий запис) **gh** як в *lough*, **ch** як в *techno*, **kh** в *khan* ітд, а **h** опиняїть ся лише в тих випадках, коли *повністю* копіюїть транслітерацію чи запис латіницею з гиншої мови, шчо, звѣсно не є доводом, бо з таким *успѣхом* можна бороти ся за еспанське **j** в *marijuna*. Також можна зазначити очевидне: в шепоті **г** і **х** мають різну вимову.

Як вже зрозумѣло, анґлієць, як-шчо його говірка не зберегла ций звук, не зможить *легко* вимовити **х**. Так само робить і зворотньо, мовник, котрий маїть в мові **х** і **ґ**, але не **г** чи **h** — не зможить їх *легко* вимовити. До того ж, певна частина українцѣв своєго часу знали непогано нѣмецьку, а тому могли використати *всѣ* згадані букви, нп. в [*Гохберґ*](//zbruc.eu/node/68557), шчо від [*Hochberg*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochberg).

Comment: І ви теж туди ж. Чому ваша відповідь починається з оцінки часу знаходження в укр. просторі того, хто задає питання? "Те, шчо ви зараз ввійшли в український простір і почали таке помѣчати, не означаїть, шчо такого не було ранѣше". Яке корисне смислове навантаження несе ця ваша репліка, і як саме вона допомогає отримати відповідь на оригінальне запитання? Відбити бажання читати вас далі? Ну, така ціль майже досягнута.

Comment: 1. Це моє питання, а не твердження, якщо ви не помітили. 2. не "твоє", а "ваше", я з тобою корів не пас. Коротше, я зрозумів, у вас тут своя домашня атмосфера, про професійне спілкування ви не чули. Всього хорошого, тусуйтесь самі, піду пошукаю де ще це питання можна *адекватно* обговорити. Хоча все ж, дякую за ваш час на розгорнуту відповідь.

Comment: Vitalii Vasylenko має рацію: деякі частини цієї відповіді порушують Code of Conduct.

Comment: **Спершу** без Code of Conduct, просто по-людьськи… Відвідувачу може бути неприємно, коли натякають на те, що він увійшов в український інфопростір лише нещодавно (незалежно від того, так це чи не так; і незалежно від того, наскільки нейтральний вигляд це твердження має для мовця; навіть якщо це твердження відповідає дійсності, такі натяки можуть виглядати зверхньо, як-от «ну, тобі ж усього N рочків, виростеш — зрозумієш» або «ти жінка, що ти можеш знати про це»).

Comment: І мені особисто було б неприємне порівняння з запитанням про відмінювання прізвищ на -ко в подібному контексті (я припускаю, що Bocchi мав на думці лише добрі наміри, а не щось на зразок «он подивіться, які нерозумні запитання трапляються, Ваше — таке ж», але я б особисто на місці відвідувача цілком міг сприйняти це так, принаймні в такому контексті).

Comment: **І формально** [Code of Conduct](//meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) каже: «Focus on the content, not the person» (причому далі додає, що навіть до контенту, а не лише до самого автора, не слід застосовувати слова, які автор може приміряти на себе).

Comment: А ще [дух Stack Exchange передбачає](//stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/10/iterating-on-inclusion/) побудову інклюзивної (inclusive) і привітної до нових членів (welcoming) спільноти. Із цього теж, по-моєму, випливає, що нам не можна, формально кажучи, натякати не таким, як ми, що вони не такі, як ми (і навіть якщо той, хто це пише, наприклад, сам увійшов в український простір лише нещодавно, тому не вбачає в цьому прояву неінклюзійності, або ж через інші причини не бачить у цьому нічого поганого — читач однаково може сприйняти це погано).

Comment: **І наостанок**… «Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate»… Хоча це правило ([як я розумію](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364)) ввели для вирішення гендерних питань, але водночас: продовжувати звертатися на «ти» до людини, яка очевидно хоче, щоб до неї зверталися на «ви», є порушенням якщо не духу, то принаймні літери цього правила.

Comment: Bocchi, чи можна Вас попросити прибрати/відредагувати відповідні місця у відповіді? (І, може, навіть перепросити у Vitalii Vasylenko? [Хоча він теж відповідав не зовсім чемно, але все-таки, мені здається, Ви {хоч і ненавмисне} зачепили його першим.])

Comment: @Bocchi, тобто ти не згодний, що «можу лише припустити, шчо ви були в московському інфопросторѣ, бо зазвичай такі чому-сь питають ся про са́ме це слово і починають наводити подібні тези, про котрих поговоримо згодом» є обговоренням особистості автора і тому порушує «focus on the content, not the person»?

Comment: @Bocchi, запитання можуть містити хибні припущення (іноді навіть дуже хибні), але не варто через це дозволити собі переходити на особистість автора (робити припущення щодо його біографії тощо).

Comment: @Bocchi, аргументовано пояснити хибність припущень у запитанні — це чудово (і це, по-моєму, набагато краще, ніж намагатися редагувати запитання). **Але при цьому неприйнятно переходити на особистість автора запитання — ось про що я кажу**.

Comment: Як модератор, поприбирав. @Bocchi, якщо вважаєте, що це неправильно, можете попросити втрутитися інших модераторів або підняти питання на ме́ті (навіть на загальній).

Comment: Гм… Гаразд. Без інших фрагментів цей, здається, виглядає вже не так погано (чи це мені вже в очах рябіє?). Але зазначу, що: (1) старіше запитання нічого не каже прямо про «було VS. стало» (це казала одна з _відповідей_ — вилучена й невидима для більшості; а саме запитання [старіше] цілком могло бути й про «навчання VS. реальність»); (2) скасування мого останнього редагування — аж ніяк не вихід (це призвело б лише до «змагання скасувань», а потім навіть не знаю, до чого що).

Comment: Звісно, що про _ко_ («старіше»).