# Геловін, Хеловін, Хеллоуїн

Tags: from-english, власні-назви, запозичені-слова

Як правильно писати назву свята? З одного боку, згідно з правилами транслітерації власних назв за правописом, на початку повинно стояти Г і зберігатися подвоєння л. Наприклад, Голлівуд пишемо саме так за тими самими правилами ([Правопис слів іншомовного походження](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm)) З іншого, найбільш близьке звучання до оригінального маємо у написанні Хеллоуїн, до того ж, усталене написання Хемінгуей. Ліна Костенко вживає виключно Геловін. І навіщо взагалі  запозичувати назву, якщо є дослівний переклад - День Усіх Святих? День Подяки, наприклад, вживаємо у перекладі.

Comment: Re: «Наприклад, Голлівуд пишемо…» + «навіщо взагалі запозичувати назву…» — вірно; «[Падубовий](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1) Ліс» — краще, аніж «Голлівуд». :-)

Comment: Див. також: [«Правила вживання букв г/х при перекладі іншомовних термінів (гакер, гостинг)»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/347).

Comment: @Sasha, правила транслітерації власних і загальних назв відрізняються, саме тому виникає колізія (для порівняння Дізель - прізвище, дизель - транспортний засіб на дизельному паливі)...

Comment: До речі, {Г/Х}е{л,лл}о{ві,уї}н — це, здається, не День усіх святих, а день/вечір/ніч перед Днем усіх святих.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для більш загального/глибокого розуміння проблеми читайте оцю відповідь:

https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/358/240

### Отже, питання стоїть так: "Як правильно писати назву свята?"

"Правильно" - значить, за правилами, значить, за правописом.

"Український правопис" 2019 року [каже таке](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf):

> Звук [h] переважно передаємо буквою г: гандбо́л, герба́рій, гі́нді, гіпо́теза, горизо́нт, го́спіс, го́спіталь, гу́мус; Га́рвард, Ге́льсінкі, Гіндуста́н, Ганніба́л, Ге́йне, Гора́цій, Люфтга́нза.
> */потім йдуть винятки, але серед них слова Гелловін немає/*

і таке:

> Подвоєння букв на позначення приголосних переважно зберігаємо у власних назвах: Андорра, ... Голландія, Марокко, ... Бетті, Джонні...

У винятках з правил слова "Гелловін" у будь-якому з варіантів написання не знаходимо. Робимо однозначачний висновок що **за правилами** писати треба так: **Гелловін**.

### Тепер щодо ваших "контрарґументів" правопису і реальності:

#### 1. Найбільш близьке звучання

> найбільш близьке звучання до оригінального маємо у написанні Хеллоуїн

Це ваше суб’єктивне твердження. Мені найближче звучить "Геловін", але я це не використовуватиму як контрарґумент, бо "найближче звучить" - це не те, як працюють правила транслітерації та перенесення іншомовних слів у мову. Є погоджені правила, які використовують навіть тоді, коли звучить і виглядає щось не так близько до ориґіналу, як могло би.

#### 2. Гемінґвей

> усталене написання Хемінгуей

Складно говорити про усталеність будь-чого, що вперше перекладалось у Радянському Союзі. На сьогодні вже маємо серію від ВСЛ, в якій прізвище класика написано інакше, що, зрештою, може призвести до **пере**усталення, позаяк це перший переклад Гемінґвея за часів сучасної України, й ми поки що не знаємо, як і що усталиться в сучасній українській мові (наприклад, у правописі 2018 року which is soon to come).

Оновлення. Правопис 2019:

> Звук [h] переважно передаємо буквою г. 
> У прізвищах та іменах людей допускається передавання звука [g] шляхом імітації іншомовного [g].

Висновок: на сьогодні **за правописом** можна писати **Гемінґвей**. Звісно, є ще варіант "Гемінгвей", але задля розрізнення різних літер, на мою думку, краще таки перший варіант.

#### 3. Навіщо взагалі?

> І навіщо взагалі запозичувати назву, якщо є дослівний переклад - День
> Усіх Святих? День Подяки, наприклад, вживаємо у перекладі.

По-перше, висловлю свою думку, що в обидвох випадках обрали просто той варіант, який швидше і легше вимовляти. "День всіх святих" просто довше казати, аніж "Гелловін", а "Сенксґівінґ дей" - аніж "День Подяки". По-друге, це вже зовсім інше питання, можете винести його окремо чимось на кшталт "Навіщо запозичувати власні назви, якщо можна їх перекладати?"

Comment: Стосовно дослівного перекладу, хочу зауважити! Halloween, англ. вимова: [ˌhæl.əʊˈiːn]; скорочено від «All Hallows' evening» — «Вечір усіх святих». А «День Усіх Святих» то є All Hallows' Day, що на наступний день, 1-го листопада, - святкуєтся Римо-Католицькою церквою. Але саме "свято" Геловіну (чи як його там) прямого відношення до Дня чи Вечіра не має. Тому, як окрема власна назва, вона не повина перекладатися українською дослівно.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>[P. Vowk](/users/240/p-vowk) розглянув лише одну букву і правило подвоєння, хоча правопис 2019 дозволяє розглянути ледь не всї випадки. Спробую виправити цю помилку, бо висновок буде трохи гинакшим.</sub>

## Першовимови

Візьму за основу [відомі словники](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_dictionaries#Selected_online_dictionaries). Якщо:

- діялект в словнику не указаний, тоді беру за основу походження словника;
- правило відмінне від МФА, то спробую додати ланку на — *[?]* — правила запису.

| UK | US | Словник |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ˌhæl.əʊˈiːn | ˌhæl.oʊˈiːn | [Cambridge](//dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/halloween?q=Halloween) |
| — | ˌha-lə-ˈwēn, ˌhä- | [Merriam-Webster](//merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Halloween) [[?](//merriam-webster.com/assets/mw/static/pdf/help/guide-to-pronunciation.pdf)] |
| hæloʊiːn | — | [Collins](//collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/halloween) |
| ˌhæləʊˈiːn, -loʊ- | — | [Longman](//ldoceonline.com/dictionary/halloween) |
| ˌhæləʊˈiːn | ˌhæləʊˈiːn | [Oxford Advanced Learnerʼs](//oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/halloween) |
| ˌhæləʊˈiːn | — | [Macmillan](//macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/halloween) |
| — | ˌhæləˈwin, -oʊˈin, ˌhɒl- | [Dictionary.com](//dictionary.com/browse/halloween) |
| — | hăl′ə-wēn, hŏl′- | [American Heritage](//ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Halloween) [[?](//ahdictionary.com/application/resources/misc/pronkey.pdf)] |

Основні варіяції…

### А

Може бути як (найчастїше) [æ], [ɑ] чи [ɒ].

Перше за правописом:

> **§ 134. Звук [æ] у словах англійського походження**
>
> Англійський звук [æ], якому на письмі відповідає англійська буква **а**, звичайно передаємо українською буквою **а**: *макінто́ш, спа́м, ча́т, ха́кер, А́лекс, А́дамс, А́длер, Га́ррісон, Ланка́стер, Манче́стер, Кана́верал, Ча́плін*; у багатьох словах за традицією цей звук передаємо через **е**: *бізнесме́н, менеджер, Бле́квуд, Ке́мерон, Ле́мберт, Пе́лл-Ме́лл, Се́лінджер, Сем, Те́тчер*.

Тобто основним записом є через **а**. Останнї дві є по сутї українськими звуком **а**. В підсумку тут немає суперечностї, якщо не згадувати традіційну **е**.

### О

Як [o] чи [ə]. Якщо з першим все очїкувано, то з другим за правописом є таке:

> **§ 135. Звук [ə:] у словах англійського походження**
>
> Англійський звук [ə:], якому найчастіше відповідають англійські буквосполучення **er**, **ir**, **or**, **ur**, **yr**, **ear**, не має в українській мові фонетичного аналога і відтворюється здебільшого українським буквосполученням **ер**: *се́рфінг, Бе́рд, Бе́ртон, Бе́ркшир, Ве́ртінг, Ерне́ст, Ерл, Ме́рфі, Че́рчилль, Ше́рлі* тощо. Деякі слова, засвоєні українською мовою в транслітерованому вигляді, передають графічну форму відповідних англійських буквосполучень: *га́мбургер, курсо́р, Во́рдсворт, І́рвінг, Урба́на* та ін.

Але тут довга голосна і з **р**, тому може не бути доводом на 100 %, тобто не можна сказати, що тут однозначно **е**. Але якщо піти за лоґікою, то тут за основою може бути **е** і традіційно за ґрафікою, тут це **о**, що не буде суперечити иншому способі вимові. Зі всїх варіянтів в:

```
[гх][ае]лл?е(у?ві|уї)н
```

Тобто через **е**, знайшов в якомусь інстаґрамі лише один раз *хелевін* (якщо побачите це як прізвище, то це не від *Halloween* і тут московське *-ін* українське *-ин*, як в *Ковалишин*). Тобто запис через **о** панує цїлковито.

### W

Як [ʊ] чи [w]. Але [декотрі](//youtube.com/watch?v=gtnlGH055TA) обґрунтовано доводять, що [ʊ] в складї діфтонґа має бути записаним як [w] в анґлійських словниках.

За правописом **в** є основним і **у** за звичайом:

> **§ 124. Букви *w*, *th* у словах англійського походження**
>
> Англійське **w** на позначення звука [w] передаємо звичайно через **в**: *віке́нд, Вашингто́н, Ве́бстер, Веллінгто́н, Ві́льсон, Вінніпе́г* та ін.; у деяких словах за традицією через **у**: *Уе́льс, уайт-спірит* та ін.

Вираз *за традицією* нічим не підкрїплений, тому зазвичай трактують *за совітською традицією*.

Можна також згадати близькі правила.

> **§ 131. Буквосполучення *au*, *ou***
>
> Буквосполучення **au**, **ou** на позначення звукосполучень [au] [ou] передаємо через **ау**, **оу**: аутса́йдер, гауптва́хта, ма́узер; Ка́унас; Кла́ус, Кра́узе, Па́уль, Фа́уст.
>
> У словах, що походять із давньогрецької й латинської мов, буквосполучення **au** звичайно передається через **ав**: *автенти́чний, автобіогра́фія, автомобі́ль, а́втор, авторите́т, автохто́н, ла́вра, Авро́ра, Маврита́нія, Павло́*. У запозиченнях із давньогрецької мови, що мають стійку традицію передавання буквосполучення au шляхом транслітерації як **ау**,
> допускаються орфографічні варіанти: *аудіє́нція* і *авдіє́нція*, *аудито́рія* і *авдито́рія*, *лауреа́т* і *лавреа́т*, *па́уза* і *па́вза*, *фа́уна* і *фа́вна*.

> **§ 133. Дифтонги [au], [ei], [ou] у словах англійського походження**
>
> Англійські дифтонги [au], [ei], [ou] звичайно передаємо, імітуючи їхнє звучання в мові оригіналу, через **ау**, **ей**, **оу**: *бра́унінг, бра́узер, Джорджта́ун, гейм, диспле́й, Дже́ймс, сно́уборд, шо́у, Сно́у, Бе́ллоу, Сі́ллітоу, Па́уелл*.
>
> Окремі слова з дифтонгами [ei] і [ou] ввійшли в українську мову в адаптованому вигляді з голосними **е**, **о**: *бебібум, брек, ле́ді, гол, готе́ль, до́пінг, смо́кінг, Бе́кон, Че́мберлен, Шекспі́р, Айве́нго, Гладсто́н, Дефо́, Джеро́м, Марло́, О́лдос, По, Лонгфе́лло.*

Тут вже можна побачити дивні розбіжності:

- **й**, тобто не **і**, але **у**, а не **в** — що є [близнюком](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA) до **й**, що можна вважати московською спадщиною, де **в** не є напівголосним, а повністю приголосним [v], що в таких випадках стає [f].
- **w** має за основу **в**, але діфтонґове — **y**, хоча тут може бути один і той самий звук.

Можете побачити запис *-уїн*. Таке можливо, якщо **w** чогось записати через **у**, тоді маємо допоміжне правило:

> **§ 129. Голосний [і]**
>
> Залежно від позиції в слові, особливостей вимови і мовної традиції букви на позначення звука [i], зокрема **і**, **у** (ігрек), **e**, буквосполучення **ea**, **ee**, **ie** і т. ін. передаємо українськими буквами **і**, **ї** та **и**.
>
> 2. **Ї** пишемо після голосного: *альтруї́ст, егої́ст, кофеї́н, маї́с, моза́їка, наї́вний, руї́на, сто́їк, теї́н; Аделаї́да, Аї́да, Каї́р, Саї́д, Таї́р, Хаї́м, Хусаї́нов*.
>
>    <sup>**Примітка.** У складних словах, де перша частина закінчується голосним, на початку другої частини пишемо **і**: *неоімперіалізм, псевдоісторичний*, так само в позиції після префікса, що закінчується на голосний; *воі́стину, доістори́чний, поінформува́ти; неіндукти́вний* і т. ін.</sup>

Також можливе *-ув-* або суто копія московського запису *-уі-*, що за вимовою радше буде *-уї-*, але за чинними правилами такі записи ніяк неможливо підкрїпити.

---

В гинших випадках жодних варіяцій немає.

### H

> **§ 122. Звуки [g], [h]**
>
> 4. Звук [h] переважно передаємо буквою **г**: *гандбо́л, герба́рій, гі́нді, гіпо́теза, горизо́нт, го́спіс, го́спіталь, гу́мус; Га́рвард, Ге́льсінкі, Гіндуста́н, Ганніба́л, Ге́йне, Гора́цій, Люфтга́нза*. За традицією в окремих словах, запозичених з європейських та деяких східних мов [h], і фонетично близькі до нього звуки передаємо буквою **х**: *хо́бі, хоке́й, хол, хо́лдинг, брахма́н, джиха́д, моджахе́д, хану́м, харакі́рі, хіджа́б, шахі́д, Алла́х, Ахме́д, Муха́ммед,
>    Сухро́б, Хакі́м, Хаммура́пі* і т. ін.

За основою є **г**, за звичайом — **х**.

### LL

Тут однозначно **л**, але одну чи дві? Тут точно не префікс, слово по сутї волосне, бо в українській це назва подїї, тому:

> **§ 128. Неподвоєні й подвоєні букви на позначення приголосних**
>
> 3. Подвоєння букв на позначення приголосних переважно зберігаємо у власних назвах: *Андо́рра, Бессеме́р, Білл, Боттіче́ллі, Гаро́нна, Голла́ндія, Ллойд, Маро́кко, Міссу́рі, Ні́цца, Я́ффа; Бе́тті, Джо́нні, Мю́ллер, Руссо́, Те́ннессі, Смо́ллетт, Кі́ркконнелл* та в загальних назвах, які від них утворені за допомогою афіксів: *андоррець, бессеме́рівський, голла́ндський,
>    марокка́нець* і т. ін.

Тобто якщо за основне, тобто переважно — **лл**. А як виняток може бути просто **л**, що теж досить поширене явище ві вжитку.

---

## Підсумок

Якщо вважати слово волосним, що скоріш за всього так і є, бо для української це просто назва одного свята, то за *основними правилами* буде **Галловін**. Запис існує не лише за правилами, а і за певним [вжитком](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%22&nfpr=1). Цїкаво, що саме такий запис стрїчає ся щонайдавнїше (тобто те, що зміг знайти) і в [1964 роцї](//diasporiana.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/books/15040/file.pdf#page=24).

Comment: Що значить, що слово *волосне*? Також не можу зрозуміти цю фразу *Тобто якщо за основне, тобто переважно — лл*.

Comment: @Yola повноголосне _власне_.

Answer (score 0):

Додам одне єдине зауваження. Транслітерація іншомовних назв умісна саме в російській мові. В українській більш доречно використовувати транскрипцію і записувати слово так як воно звучить в мові оригіналу, тобто наприклад Worcester слід писати Вустер, а не Ворсестер, Leicester має бути Лестер, а не Лесестер, Houston має бути Г’юстон, якщо це місто в штаті Техас, і Говстон, якщо це вулиця на нью-йоркському Менгетені, бо так по-різному одне і те ж написання вимовляють американці. З такої точки зору більш доречно використовувати "Хеловін", або "Геловін", бо початковий звук все ж відрізняеться від нашого "х" і наближений до "г". Також не може йти мови і про подвоєння, бо в англійській немає ніяких подвоєних звуків у вимові. Наголос на останній склад. Якщо бажаєте заснувати українське написання не на британській а на американській версії то можна "Халовін" з тим же наголосом.